# How to prevent second tap on UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview

There is `UICollectionView` with cell. By tapping on the cell subview should be added.

Everything works, but... if I quickly tap second or third time, it add two or three subviews...

So how to properly do that?

This is the code of `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`:

```
recipeDetailView = [[RecipeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

[recipeDetailView.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgRecipe.jpg"]]];
[recipeDetailView.view setFrame: myFrame];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [recipeDetailView.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                     [self.view addSubview:recipeDetailView.view];
                     [self addChildViewController:recipeDetailView];
                     [recipeDetailView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [recipeDetailView slideViewAdd];
                 }];
```

Comment: Look into `- (BOOL) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` just add all your code into this.

```
 if(recipeDetailView ==  nil)
 {

  //copy all your codes from above question.

 }
```

And when your are  removing the view just set the recipeDetailView to nil.

```
 recipeDetailView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either disable user interaction for a short time after the tap is detected.

Or, use a gesture recognizer to detect the tap, and another for multiple taps, and require the multiple tap recognizer to fail before the single tap recognizer fires.